# Добавление custom endpoint в REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Нужно добавить custom endpoint для пользовательского типа записей (тип называется ponds) для получения записей, в которых определённый meta_key имеет определённое значение meta_value. Вот мой код:

```
public function pondid_endpoint( $data) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'ponds',
        'meta_key' => 'pond_id',
        'meta_value' => $data['pond_id']
    ) );
    if (empty($posts)) {
        return new WP_Error('empty list', 'there is no post with this pond id', array('status' => 404));
    }
    return $posts;
}

public function add_routes() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/ponds', '/pond_id/(?P<pond_id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'pondid_endpoint',
        ) );
}
```

В __construct() прописал следующее:

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', [$this, 'register_routes'] );
    $this->add_routes();
```

Но после этого выдаёт ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function register_route() on null in /www/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 77
```

Что это может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас нет данного метода. думаю cтоит сделать вот так

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', [ $this, 'add_routes' ] );
```

так же нужно изменить этот метод, потому что в callback нужно передать область вилимости текущего обьекта

```
public function add_routes() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/ponds', '/pond_id/(?P<pond_id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => [ $this, 'pondid_endpoint' ],
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Да, значит, я неправильно понял. Но благодаря Вам стало ясно. Спасибо.